# there are function that remove the directions if that opposite them but i don't understand it

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how we use stack[stack.length - 1] and it is empty and how it has a value

```js
function dirReduc(arr) {
  const stack = [];
  for (let direction of arr) {
    // Check if the current direction cancels out the last one on the stack
    if (
      (direction === 'NORTH' && stack[stack.length - 1] === 'SOUTH') ||
      (direction === 'SOUTH' && stack[stack.length - 1] === 'NORTH') ||
      (direction === 'EAST' && stack[stack.length - 1] === 'WEST') ||
      (direction === 'WEST' && stack[stack.length - 1] === 'EAST')
    ) {
      // Remove the last direction from the stack as it cancels out
      stack.pop();
    } else {
      // Otherwise, push the current direction onto the stack
      stack.push(direction);
    }
  }
  return stack;
}
```

Comment: `stack[stack.length - 1]` is the last element of the array. The code you posted is broken because `stack` is a local variable in the function, initialized to an empty array, so `stack[stack.length - 1]` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy — It won't *always* be `undefined`. It will have had a value pushed it to it by the time you hit the second time around the `for` loop.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with example input and expected output. And also try to rewrite the question so it has a relevant and understandable title and move the description to the actual question with added information. It is really hard to understand what you are asking now

Comment: @Quentin oh yea good point, I ignored the loop. I wish that `stack[stack.length - 1]` were stashed in a local `const` in the loop instead of being repeated 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access an index of an array without an explicit value (such as `stack[-1]`) then you will get [the `undefined` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Undefined) (which isn't equal to any of the strings it is compared against so triggers the `else` branch).

(And by the time you go around the `for` loop for the second time, the array will not be empty any more because that else branch `push`es a value into it).

---

This is a good time to learn how to [use a debugger](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/step_through_code/index.html) so you can step though code and observe how it works.